# How to use exec_params where params in ('','','')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, parameters, pg

I'm use

```
sql = "Select * from table where type in ($1)
pg_con = PG::Connection.open(myserver)
pg_con.exec_params(sql, [get_type_action])
```

get_type_action returns all type in format "'test1', 'test2', 'test3'", etc... count of type 0-90.
All code returns 0 rows. I started looking for the problem. I entered one value "test1" without '' instead of a function and got the desired result. But trying to enter multiple values "test1, test2", I get 0 rows. what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1**
I can'use active record for this. But I'm find  example

```
a = ['alpha', 'bravo', 'ccharlie']
b = $conn.exec_params( %Q{ SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE fieldname IN ( $1 ) }, [ PG::TextEncoder::Array.new.encode(a) ] )
```

I try it, but not working yet. Can  try to do something similar, taking an example as a basis? Or is he wrong?

Comment: You have the tag ruby-on-rails, could you instead use ActiveRecord? `YourTable.where(type: [...])`

Comment: I send sql qeury on remote sql server, and work with resul on my ruby on rails app

Comment: Just as a suggestion... Could you still use `ActiveRecord` (or [Sequel](https://medium.com/@bacarini/multiple-databases-using-sequel-in-a-rails-app-e64bc0c83e2d), or whatever) if you create the model with [a different database connection](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html)? That might be easier than having to hand-craft all of this SQL. Just because the database is on a different server, that doesn't mean your app can't connect to it.

Comment: I understand what you are talking about, then that the question is just an example. in a real task, there is another request that will change periodically. The purpose is precisely to do this with sql. I would be grateful for any help

Comment: @Awesome Could you then show us your real task, please?

Comment: `PG::TextEncoder::Array` makes a [Postgres Array](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html). You can use [`any`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-SEARCHING) as `field = any($1)` with an array, but it's a hack around SQL building problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PG will not build SQL for you. Each element of the `in` list must be its own parameter.

```
sql = "select * from table where type in ($1, $2, $3)"
pg_con = PG::Connection.open(myserver)
p pg_con.exec_params(sql, ["a", "b", "c"]).values
```

But since you're using Ruby on Rails there's no need to write simple SQL. Use [ActiveRecord](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html). Let's say the table name is things. Make an ActivceRecord called `Thing` and then call [`where`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions) with an array as the value.

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord
end

things = Thing.where(type: ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: Your Active Record suggestion is good too, maybe add as an alternative?

Comment: the problem is that the count of parameters can be different from 0 to 99. Therefore, I cannot insert fixed $1, $2, $3

Comment: @Awesome Yes, you'll have to generate the SQL to match the number of parameters. This is why there is ActiveRecord to do it for you.

Comment: In comment on question I'm write what i cant use Active Record for this. Please dont' change subject.

Comment: @Awesome You either need to construct the SQL string yourself with the correct number of arguments, or you need a SQL builder. I highly recommend using a SQL builder, and Rails has one: ActiveRecord (and Arel) or the even more powerful [sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel). They're more flexible than you think. If you post your real issue we can help.